# Is this supremum infinite or finite?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, supremum-and-infimum

Given two numbers $x\in (0,1)$ and $y\in (0,1)$, think of the expression
$\min_{n\ge 1} \frac{1-x}{(1-xy)y^{n-1}(1-x^n)}$.

Does the supremum of this expression, namely, 
$\sup_{x,y\in (0,1)}\min_{n\ge 1} \frac{1-x}{(1-xy)y^{n-1}(1-x^n)}$
be finite or infinite?

I greatly appreciate your help!! I would like to prove this my mechanical engineering research :)